# How to install package from NuGet

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to install [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Sheets.v4/) package from NuGet.

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet

if(Get-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -ea SilentlyContinue)
{
    Install-Package -Name "Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" -Source NuGet -MinimumVersion "1.54.0.2371"
}
```

But i get this error:

```
Install-Package : Dependency loop detected for package 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4'.
At line:5 char:5
+     Install-Package -Name "Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" -Source NuGet
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : Deadlock detected: (Google.Apis.Sheets.v4:String) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DependencyLoopDetected,Microsoft.PowerShell.PackageManagement.Cmdlets.InstallPackage
```

What i'm doing wrong, and how to properly install packages from NuGet?
PowerShell version: 5.1

Comment: I can confirm that I have the same, failing result using pwsh 7.1.4. `Install-Package: Dependency loop detected for package 'Google.Apis.Sheets.v4'.`

Comment: Some people report adding switch `-SkipDependencies`, but.. you may lose functionality by doing that. If you know what dependencies are needed, you can of course load these separately.

Answer (score -1):

If you can't install the package from CLI, you can directly add this

`<PackageReference Include="Google.Apis.Sheets.v4" Version="1.54.0.2371" />`
in your <project_name>.csproj file.
This approach worked for me.